# Session issue with chrome in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session-state

I have used session to store some config setting in MVC3 application, in my case i have made another class called sessionhelper to maintain session property with get and set property on app_code folder as per below

```
 public static string IsPaypalSupport
        {
            get
            {
                if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["IsPaypalSupport"] == null)
                {
                    //if session is expired then redirect to home page


                }
                return Convert.ToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["IsPaypalSupport"]);
            }
            set { System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["IsPaypalSupport"] = value; }
        }
```

On Home page (homecontroller) i set this property to true and redirect to inner page now , in inner page's controller i have used this property set viewbag as per below

```
ViewBag.SupportPaypal = bool.Parse(app_code.SessionHelper.IsPaypalSupport.ToString());
```

Now when i hit F5 then it will call again,
In Firefox session value still available so it will return correct value but
In Chrome session value will be null so error

**Why every request in chrome will make session to null?**

**How i need to handle this null session , i would like to put redirection to home page (index of home controller) whenever session is expired so how can i do it in sessionhelper class?**

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <sessionState cookieless="true"  mode="InProc" timeout="30" > </sessionState>
```

Try this, will work in CHrome

Answer (score 1):

Maybe cookies is turned off in chrome or it setted not to domain but for some folder or subdomain.

Comment: I haven't used cookies, what should be issue with that?

Comment: So how do you store sessionID on client? via url?

Comment: As per @amit answer i am not using cokieless session and also cookie is enabled for chrome, what should be issue with it?